# $P(X < Y)$ for two independent random variables X and Y

Tags: probability

We have two uniform, independent and continuous stochastic variables

```
X is U(0,4)
Y is U(0,6)
```

What is `P(X < Y)`?

**My attempt at a solution**

Instead of asking "What is the probability that X < Y" we ask "What is the probability that X below or equal to some number x and that Y is above this number?"

```
P(X < Y) = 
P(X < x INTERSECTION Y > x) = 
P(X < x) * P(Y > x) = 
P(X < x) * (1 - P(Y < x)) =
Fx(x) * (1 - Fy(x))
```

Now all we should need to do is go through all possibilities of x. However it's not quite that simple, since they have two different upper boundaries (4 and 6) we will get bogus results for X when we go above 4 and we won't capture the full range of Y if we only go to 4.

Also, I don't know what kind of iteration we are supposed to do. Should we do something like this:

```
Integrate( fx(x) (1 - fy(x)) dx) from 0 to 6
```

Comment: [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Are you familiar with joint distributions?

Comment: Is that the same as a 2d-stochastic variable? (seems like it , so yes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The joint density of $X,Y$ is 
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\frac{1}{24} \quad \text{ if } \quad (x,y)\in (0,4)\times(0,6).$$
Denote $A \in \mathbb R^2 $ set such that $x<y$, then the desired probability is
$$P(X<Y)=\int\int_A f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy =\int_0^{4} \int_{x}^{6} \frac{1}{24} dy dx $$
using Fubini theorem.

Answer (score 4):

> we ask "What is the probability that X below or equal to some number x and that Y is above this number?" ...  Now all we should need to do is go through all possibilities of x.

Sort of.  Try: "For all possible values of $X$, what is the probability that $Y$ is greater?   We integrate this over the support of $X$ weighted by its probability density (since the random variables are independent.)"

Thus what you are attempting is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(X<Y) ~=~& \int_0^4 \mathsf P(Y>x)~f_X(x)\operatorname d x 
\\[1ex] =~& \int_0^4 \frac{6-x}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\operatorname dx
\\[1ex] =~& 1-\frac{1}{24}\int_0^4 x\operatorname dx
\\[1ex] =~& \frac 23
\end{align}$$